Why does a vehicle's GPS tracker go offline when a metal chain is attached with vehicle chassis?
From my colleagues, It has come to my knowledge that attaching a 5-6 feet metal short-link chain under a truck (Mazda T3500) that is installed with a GPS vehicle tracker can suddenly cause the tracker to go offline. An offline tracker means that the GSM module is not functioning properly.
I searched a lot on this but did not find any clues. I aim to fix this issue. I assume that the truck has become a Faraday Cage when the chain is attached to it. Maybe something is going on when the road and vehicle chassis touch via a chain.
The GSM module is using Quad-band 850/900/1800/1900 MHz and the tracker is installed inside the dashboard. Following is the picture of tracker's PCB.



"It has come to my knowledge that attaching a large chain under a vehicle that is installed with a GPS vehicle tracker can suddenly cause the tracker to go offline." That sounds extremely much like a myth. What's your source on this? (If this is an experimental result that you have made yourself, that's a valid source. "I have seen it somewhere on the internet that someone claims that" isn't. We're not in the business of debunking everything: if you make a surprising claim, it's your job to back it up, not our to debunk the claim. Making a nonsense claim takes no effort at all.)

My colleagues (more than one) have eye-witnessed this behaviour. It disturbed me as well because it seemed very much unrealistic.

So, then we need more info about the GSM module and the car and the chain and the speed and how they observed this. I (and millions of professional lorry drivers) can tell you from personal experience that cellular connectivity of a car is completely unaffected by pulling a large metal object behind your car. So far my best guess is: "pulling a metal chain makes your car rumble, your previous question indicate non-professional installation of electronics, so a loose contact would be a good explanation".

It is a Mazda T3500 truck. The GSM module is using Quad-band 850/900/1800/1900 MHz and the chain is a metal short-link chain, strong and large enough to pull trucks. There is no external antenna with wire or connector. Image is attached above.

where is the module mounted? How long is the chain?

The chain would be 5-6 feet long. See the area to insert a SIM card in the image.

Where on the car is the module mounted?

Tracker is installed inside the dashboard and I don’t know if it is in the middle, right or left side.

Thanks, can you add all the information you've been giving in the comments here, from that it's your colleagues who observe this to the chain, car and tracker placement information, to your question itself, please?

My guess:  The body of most cars has a lot of steel in it, but it is floating above GND (literally and electrically) because of the tires.  The chain creates a non-perfect but much lower impedance to GND, and the car becomes a better approximation of a Faraday cage.

not sure it works like this: Car windows, wheelbase openings, bumpers etc are RF-transparent openings significantly larger than involved wavelengths

another indication is that you can use your phone inside the car without problems while the car is being filled up, and that definitely connects the car chassis to a well-grounded point.

I wasn't saying it was the answer, or anything close to a true cage, just a contributing factor.  And, pretty sure bumpers are steel under plastic covers.  Mine are fine, Swedish steel.

A Faraday cage does not need grounding.

There's two things that I think are thinkable here:

Since your vehicle is a tall-window truck, and the GSM device is situated close to the front window, we should have no "grounding" effects that matter here. What I can't fully rule out is sparking caused by road/chain interaction having causing electromagnetic disturbance. You can test that: if the same module in a truck driving next to a truck with chains get disrupted, then it's emissions by the chain. I'd be surprised! But I find it hard to rule out completely.
The thing I think is more likely is that you get mechanical vibrations, possibly in the ultrasonic range, which couple into the PCB; and that there's either oscillators, filters or capacitors that exhibit susceptibility to microphonic effects at these frequencies. I'd probably try to put the electronics in a styrofoam box, and put that on a piece of soft foam, and look whether that improves the situation. At this point, however, you really should already be in contact with the vendor of these devices and be renegotiating. Something that's not vibration-proof for automotive usage seems to me to be quite underperforming!
And of course: make sure your experimental basis is sufficient to make any conclusions. A couple anecdotal observations that the GPS fails when the chain is dragged are important, but it also means that you need to do real statistics about how often your devices have outages, and start calling truck drivers during their shift about whether they're currently dragging a chain or are doing something "special" other than that when their GSM modules fail.


I suspect your second point. The GPS module likely makes use of a SAW filter: https://www.mdpi.com/2571-631X/1/1/4
